# Highcharts-NG is only listening to some of my chart config options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am trying to utilize highcharts-ng in my angular application. I've never used high charts which is causing me some pains...

I'm trying to create a directive for my charts. I understand the chart is already  a directive but I wish to put it in a directive so I can load data into them from my database more easily as I will have several per page.

The chart is showing the correct data but as a line chart instead of a bar chart. The height variable is all so not translating into the chart.

I included a photo of the current results below. [Notice it is not a 100px tall bar chart]

[image: The wrong stuffff]

```
angular.module('app').directive('forcastChart', function () {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: '<highchart config="chartConfig"></highchart>',

    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

        $scope.title="CHAFRT?"

        $scope.chartConfig = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                }
            }, 
            series: [{
                showInLegend: false,
                data: [10, 15, 12]
            }],
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['a','b','c']
            }], 
            size: {
               height: 100
            },
            title: {
                text: null  
            },
            loading: false,
            chart: {
                type: 'columns'
            }
        }
    }//end of link
}});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up the config in the directive controller rather than in the link function it works and keeps the categories - [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/wjgLqncq/). Not sure why, I guess it is something with how the highcharts-ng library interacts with the parent directive scope.

```
angular.module('app', ['highcharts-ng']).directive('forcastChart', function () {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {},
    template: '<highchart config="chartConfig"></highchart>',

    controller: function($scope, $element){
       $scope.title="CHAFRT?"

        $scope.chartConfig = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                }
            }, 
            series: [{
                showInLegend: false,
                data: [10, 15, 12]
            }],
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['a','b','c']
            }], 
            size: {
               height: 100
            },
            title: {
                text: null  
            },
            loading: false,
            chart: {
                type: 'columns'
            }
        }
    }
}});
```

Comment: Yep, it must be some odd interference between the two. This works perfectly and for those wondering you can use the "link" function and "directive controller" in the same directive fine with this.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
 series: [{
              type:'bar',
              data: [10, 15, 12]
            }]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works, but it looses my x-axis labels 
[code]  categories: ['a','b','c'] [/code]